# About the minimal equivalence relation identifying some points.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I am solving a problem where I have a set $X$ together with a subset of elements that I want to identify. To do this I consider the minimal equivalence relation identifying these points.

I have a function $f: X \to Y$ that satisfies $f(x)=f(y)$ for every two points that I have declared to be equivalent. Can I conclude that this function factorizes to the quotient?

A bit of context:

For a given ring $A$ I am trying to show that the colimit of the functor 
$$F: Fields \to Set$$
$$ K \mapsto Hom(A,K)$$

is in bijection with the set of prime ideals of $A$.To do this I need to define a function of the colimit and  I need to check that it is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  The point is that equivalence relations are the same thing as "equality after applying some function".  In particular, there is an equivalence relation $\sim_f$ defined by $x\sim_f y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$.  This equivalence relation contains all your pairs of points, so by definition it contains the minimal equivalence relation (call it $\sim$) you use to define the quotient.  That is, $x\sim y$ implies $x\sim_f y$, so $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x\sim y$.  This says exactly that $f$ descends to a well-defined function on the quotient.

Answer (score 3):

yes $f$ factorized via the quotient for it the relationship you
have defined on the points is finer than that associated to $f$ ie
$xRy\Rightarrow xR_fy$ where $R_f$ the equivalence  relation
associated to$f$, $R_f$ is defined  as: $xR_fy $ iff $f(x)=f(y)$.